# Why does the ls command require a dash before its parameters but for tar command, the dash is optional?

Tags: linux, tar, ls, arguments

I am new to Ubuntu and I am trying hard to understand the command line.

When I want to see the contents of a tar file I use:

> tar tf tarfile.tar

But when I want to see a listing of all file if I use:

> ls a filename

It says:

> ls: cannot access a: No such file or directory

Why is that?

Why is the minus sign "-" required for one command and not for the other?

Comment: The title and question body don't match.  The title asks why it's wrong to use `-t` with `tar` (A: It isn't; modern versions of `tar` accept `-t`).  The question body asks the opposite (why it's wrong to omit the `-` for options to other programs).

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1168/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tar command is one of the oldest commands in *nix.  It was created long long ago to do tape archives where data was stored on tape drives.

When the utility was written, the current standard of putting a dash to indicate a parameter was not yet invented.

It is optional for tar, but mandatory for almost every other command.

Comment: [Here is a similar answer, for the same question.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13573/why-use-superflous-dash-to-pass-option-flags-to-tar)